# Use Grönwall's proof to prove boundedness of ODE's solution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals, solution-verification

We have a function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, positive and increasing. Let $u:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable and
$$|u'(t)|\leq F(|u(t)|), \hspace{1.0cm}  t\in(a,b)$$
If
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{F(s)}ds=+\infty$$
Prove that $u$ is bounded on $(a,b)$.

My idea is to get inspiration from this proof of Grönwall's inequality:

> **Grönwall's lemma**
>
> Let $\omega\in C^1(a,b)$, if  $\exists \epsilon>0, Q>0:\forall t\in (a,b)$ is 
>   $$|\omega'(t)| \leq  \epsilon+Q(|\omega(t)|$$
>   so 
>   $$|\omega(t)|\leq \left(\frac{\epsilon}{Q}+|\omega(t_0)|\right)e^{Q|t-t_0|}$$

---

> **Proof**
>
> Let $z(t)=\sqrt{\omega^2(t)+\sigma^2}\geq \omega(t)$
>   $$|z'(t)|=|\frac{2\omega(t)\omega'(t)}{2\sqrt{\omega^2(t)+\sigma^2}}|\leq |\omega'(t)|\leq \epsilon+Q|\omega(t)|\leq \epsilon +Qz(t)$$
>   $$z'(t)\leq \epsilon +Qz(t)$$
>   $$\frac{z'(t)}{\epsilon+Qz(t)}\leq 1$$
>   Notice that $\frac{d}{dt}ln(\epsilon+Qz(t))=\frac{Qz'(t)}{\epsilon+Qz(t)}$
>   $$\implies \frac{z'(t)}{\epsilon+Qz(t)}=\frac{1}{Q}\frac{d}{dt}ln(\epsilon+Qz(t))\leq 1 \implies \frac{d}{dt}ln(\epsilon+Qz(t))\leq Q $$
>   Integrating from $t_0$ to $t$:
>   $$\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{d}{dt}ln(\epsilon+Qz(t))dt=\int_{t_0}^{t}Q$$
>   $$ln\left(\frac{\epsilon+Qz(t)}{\epsilon+Qz(t_0)}\right)\leq Q(t-t_0)$$
>   $$z(t)\leq \left(\frac{\epsilon}{Q}+z(t_0)\right)e^{Q(t-t_0)}$$
>   And because $z(t)\geq \omega(t)$,
>   $$|\omega(t)|\leq \left(\frac{\epsilon}{Q}+|\omega(t_0)|\right)e^{Q(t-t_0)}$$

But I don't know how to use the improper integral given to me in this verification.

Comment: It should be Gronw**a**ll.

Comment: @Dmitry: and even Grönwall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $G(x)=\int_1^x\frac1{F(s)}ds$. If $|u(t)|>1$ for $t\in(t_0,t_1)$, then inside this interval
$$
\frac{d}{dt} G(|u(t)|)=G'(|u(t)|)\frac{u(t)\cdot u'(t)}{|u(t)|}=\frac{u(t)\cdot u'(t)}{|u(t)|\,F(|u(t)|)}
$$
which is smaller than one in absolute value, $G(|u(t)|)\le G(|u(t_0)|)+|t-t_0|$. This now means that this expression can not reach infinity in finite time, which translates via the inverse of $G$ to $|u(t)|$. So the solution is bounded over all finite intervals.

---

Or perhaps simpler to follow, let $v(t)$ be the solution of $v'(t)=F(v(t))$ with $v(0)=1+|u(0)|$. Then at any point $t>0$ you have
$$
|u(t)|-v(t)\le |u(0)|-v(0)+\int_0^t[|u'(s)|-v'(s)]ds\le -1+\int_0^t[F(|u(s)|)-F(v(s))]
$$
Assuming that there exists a point with $|u(t)|=v(t)$ leads to a contradiction, as the inequality above gives $|u(t)|+1\le v(t)$ for the smallest such $t$. Now the boundedness  of $v$ follows from the separation-of-variables method and the given property of $F$.

A similar argument holds for the other direction in comparing $|u(-t)|$ and $v(t)$ for $t>0$.

Comment: after proving that $G(|u(t)|)$ is bounded on a finite time, how can I  conclude that $|u(t)|$ is bounded?

Comment: $G$ is positive and monotonously increasing to infinity, which translates to its inverse function. So if $G(|u(t)|)$ is bounded by $M=G(x)$, then $|u(t)|<x$.

Comment: How do we use the fact that $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{F(s)}ds=+\infty$?

Comment: For instance to ensure the existence of a growing sequence $x_n$ with $\int_1^{x_n}\frac{ds}{F(s)}=2^n$. Then if $G(|u(t)|)\le 2^n$, one can conclude that $|u(t)|\le x_n$.

Comment: Why the fact that $|u(t)|\leq x_n$ implies the boundedness of $|u(t)|$, if $x_n$ is a growing sequence?

Comment: You get one $n$ so that $2^n$ (or however you want to parametrize the sequence) is an upper bound for $G(|u(t)|)$ over some interval $I$ around some $t_0$. Then $x_n$ is a bound for $|u(t)|$ over the same interval. No escape to infinity is possible in finite time.

Comment: Or to come back to the argument in my first comment, if $M$ is a bound of $G(|u(t)|)$ over $t\in I$, then one can find an $x$ with $G(x)=M$ which implies $|u(t)|\le x$ for $t\in I$. For the existence of that $x$ you need $G(x)\to\infty$ for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been so kind and helpful.